# Mysql join 2 tables that are unrelated to each other

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to join 2 tables that are completly unrelated to each other?

I have 2 tables, named 'writes' and 'posts' 
The posts are messages that people wrote on their own profile
The writes are messages that people wrote on another users profile.

While loading a users profile, i want a row of al their posts and writes on their timeline. How can i achive this?

Is there a way to join these tables together? Or should i make an complete other system to load the timeline?

Things like

```
SELECT q1, q2 FROM
(SELECT posts.* as q1 FROM writes as a) t1, 
(SELECT writes.* as q2 FROM posts as b) t2
```

didn't work for me

And select * from posts, writes gives me an cross join table.

The tables has the following structure:

posts:

```
#1 id int
#2 user_id int
#3 post varchar (4096)
#4 last_changed datetime
#5 posted_at datetame
#6 type varchar (32) (In the post case it is 'POST')
```

write:

```
#1 id int
#2 writer_id int (the user_iud who has written it)
#3 user_id int (the user_id of the person this write is written on)
#4 written varchar (the text)
#5 last_changed datetime
#6 written_at datetime
#7 type varchar (32) (in this case it it 'WRITE')
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine results of Different Select queries into one using [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). Since there will not be any duplicates between the two `Select` statements, you can make it more efficient using `UNION ALL`

Also, to do [overall sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642877/mysql-join-2-tables-that-are-unrelated-to-each-other/52642905?noredirect=1#comment92219206_52642905), you need to take the complete result-set in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), and use an `Order By` clause. You can set it in Ascending or Descending order, using `ASC` or `DESC` respectively.

We also need to ensure that **number of columns** returned by both the `SELECT` statements are same:

```
SELECT dt.id, 
       dt.writer_id, 
       dt.user_id, 
       dt.post, 
       dt.last_changed, 
       dt.posted_at, 
       dt.type 
FROM 
(
 (
  SELECT id, 
         user_id AS writer_id, 
         user_id, 
         post, 
         last_changed, 
         posted_at, 
         type
  FROM posts
 )

  UNION ALL 

 (
  SELECT id, 
         writer_id, 
         user_id, 
         written AS post, 
         last_changed, 
         written_at AS posted_at, 
         type
  FROM writes
 )
) AS dt 
ORDER BY dt.posted_at ASC
```

Documentation details:

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.
>
> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same
>   data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first
>   statement should have the same type as the first column selected by
>   the other statements.)
>
> If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the
>   types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account
>   the values retrieved by all of the SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This query gives me an '#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns' error

Comment: @ward Please share your table structures in the question.

Comment: Update: added the table structure

Comment: It looks like it is working right now. So basicly what i have been doing wrong al the time is selecting too many (and the wrong) variables. I have one more question, how can i order them by the posted_at time?

Comment: @ward do you want to order them in individual select results. or you want to do an overall sorting ?

Comment: just an overall sorting will be fine

Comment: @ward please check the updated answer. Do consider upvoting the answer as well. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
select  id ,user_id,post,last_changed,posted_at,type from posts
 union all    
select  id,user_id,written,last_changed,written_at,type from write
```

**Rule of union all**

```
Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
The columns must also have similar data types
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order
```